# passing params to routed with react-navigation but result undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Hi I am new to react native and trying to learn few things. I am trying to pass a data from rest API Laravel . Here is my code

```
if (responseData.items) {
          this.props.navigation.push('SearchResults', {users: responseData.items });
          } else {
            this.setState({ errorMessage: 'No results found'});
          }
```

my code navigator

```
const Sp2hpStack = createStackNavigator({
```

Search: SearchScreen,
  SearchResults: SearchResults,
});

my code Result

```
render() {
const { users } = this.props.navigation.state;
console.log(users);
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <Text>email : {users.email} </Text>
  </View>
);
```

}

but result is undefined
please help me

Answer (score 1):

To get the params from a route, you can access them through **this.props.navigation.getParam('users', [])**

PS: the empty array is optional and this will be the default value if users is undefined

Comment: same result is undefined

Comment: Okay, could you add the code for the entire SearchResults component?

Answer (score 0):

please try with - `const { users } = this.props.navigation.state.params;` not `const { users } = this.props.navigation.state;`

Comment: same result is undefined

Comment: Please make sure responseData.items are not undefined. also the navigator should be as following:


`const Sp2hpStack = createStackNavigator ({`
`Search: {`
`screen: SearchScreen`
`},`
`SearchResults: {`
`screen: SearchResults`
`},`
`});`

Comment: problem is solved i use console.log(users[0].email);